# Iterate through two lists simultaneously and remove from one if exists in the other

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to check if the ID of a `similar` result exists in the `exact` results already and then exclude that result, I'm just unsure of the best way to do so.

I assume I'd have to find a way to iterate through both lists, then try something like `if similar.ID != exact.ID` and pass that to a variable to pass to the Jinja2 template.

The queries are being done with SQL-Alchemy like so;

```
exact_assets = Motor.query.filter_by(**filter_data).all()
similar_assets = Motor.query.filter_by(**similar_filter_data).all()

# Something like

# for similar_asset, exact_asset in similar_assets, exact_assets:
#     if similiar_asset.id == asset.id:
#        similar_asset.pop(id)
```

I know that syntax isn't correct, or even functional with a list or dict (?) but hopefully it is able to express what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: We can't debug anything without the relevant code. Pare your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here.

Comment: Can you detach your actual question from all that boilerplate? When I read the title I thought "I know for sure how to do this". But now I don't even know what the question is.

Comment: @timgeb Sorry about that, this should be much better.

Comment: @xGlorify that's still something I can't paste into my interpreter. Why can't you provide two example lists and the desired output?

Comment: @timgeb The problem seems to be iterating through the list of objects the query returns, then accessing attributes on those objects to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an list of keys to compare with (assuming that equality means same id from your code)

```
exact_assets_ids = [item.id for item in exact_assets]
```

Then filter your similar assets

```
final_assets = [item for item in similar_assets if item.id in exact_assets_ids]
```

Update: Just noticed that it is the intersection set :)

```
final_set = list(set(similar_assets) or set(exact_assets))
```

But in this case you should implement `Motor.__eq__`

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I just changed it a bit to exclude item.id from exact_assets_ids by adding `Not in` instead of `in`.